# What can webkit do?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

Since there are more and more apps going the web way (like Phonegap, Appcelerator over the mobile and desktop apps development and the ones that I don't know yet), I am wondering what kind of role the web engine (seems the famous engine is webkit) is playing now and in the future?

A web engine is capable of rendering HTML and CSS(for interface), interpreting Javascript(for programming logic), and combining hardware features (like the geo-location, Accelerometer in iPhone web). It seems the web engine has become an extremely powerful "language" and also makes the "coding" much more easier(just writing "web code"). Will it be "ubiquitous all around the apps"?

It's just my point of view and correct me if I am wrong.

My question is:

Where can I find some good examples using webkit engine? I am really new to this and hope the examples are fair easy to learn and use. Thank you~

Comment: I wouldn't say WebKit is any more famous than Gecko or Trident.... certainly not by market share. Maybe in innovation.

Comment: This is rather subjective + there's no actual question

Comment: Sorry I've modified the question and I just want to find some good examples of webkit and to see what it is really capable of beyond the "web browser"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebKit has implemented a lot of cool standards-based features:

- [HTML5 web sockets](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/12/web-sockets-now-available-in-google.html)
- [HTML5 video and audio](http://webkit.org/blog/140/html5-media-support/)
- [HTML5 web workers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/)
- [HTML5 geolocation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)
- [Client-side database storage](http://webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/)
- [Application cache](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/)
- [CSS 3 animations](http://webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/)
- [CSS 3 Gradients](http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/)
- [CSS 3 3d Transforms](http://webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome OS is Google's project to basically make a browser engine into a whole OS

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QRO3gKj3qw

Sounds like your train of thought tho not quite sure what your question is sorry